# Ckeditor gem issue with production mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ckeditor

I'm using the [CKEditor gem](https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor). My config for `application.js` and `routes.rb` are like the followings:

```
# application.js
//= require ckeditor/init

# routes.rb
mount Ckeditor::Engine => '/ckeditor'
```

The gem works fine in development mode, but when moving to the production mode, I got the error 404 when browsers request the js and css files in ckeditor folder:

```
GET http://mydomain/assets/ckeditor/config.js?t=D2LI 404 (Not Found)
GET http://mydomain/assets/ckeditor/skins/moono/editor.css?t=D2LI 404 (Not Found)
GET http://mydomain/assets/ckeditor/lang/vi.js?t=D2LI 404 (Not Found)
GET http://mydomain/assets/ckeditor/styles.js?t=D2LI 404 (Not Found)
```

Please help me to fix my ckeditor route config. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'll need to explicitly direct Rails to precompile your CKEditor assets in production:

```
# config/application.rb
config.assets.precompile += Ckeditor.assets
```

Then, within your production environment, force a precompilation:

```
rake assets:precompile:all
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case I was using Rails 4 and deploying to Heroku. I found I had to precompile the assets locally first, then commit the `/public/assets/ckeditor` directory and deploy. Worked after that, although I don't really fancy this solution.

Answer (score 2):

I had some trouble with only the lang files not being found in Rails 5.

I had to do this to get it working ->`Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w(ckeditor/* ckeditor/lang/*)` in `assets.rb`.

I don't know why the first declaration doesn't just include the lang folder in the first place (it works for the adapters, plugins, and skins folders). Bug maybe?

Comment: you can try this: Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w(ckeditor/**/*)

Answer (score 1):

Just upgrade the ckeditor gem to latest version(~> 4.1.0) in case if you are using Rails 4.

check more update here https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor