# Text editor for rails_admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-admin, bootstrap-wysihtml5

`rails_admin` gived me 2 options of text editors for my text areas.

1. CKEditor
2. Wysihtml5

I need image uploading feature in my text area!
CKEditor works in development, but doesn't in production environment. Some kind of assets path trouble, I guess.
Wysihtml5 field doesn't have uploading images feature! It just gives option of inserting image through url. I want uploader (paperclip, carrierwave, or smth similar).

What should I do to have a text editor with image-uploading feature?

PS: if you have some other text editors for `rails_admin` on your mind, give some manuals of installing pls.

Comment: Take a look at this (hopefully it should solve your CKEditor problem) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17636564/ckeditor-gem-issue-with-production-mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using the [rich text editor](https://github.com/bastiaanterhorst/rich), which works with rails_admin. It works well with production because it doesn't require weird precompile, and its image uploading feature is fantastic. I used ckeditor with rails_admin but switched to rich, and I'm much happier with it.